# Filter multiple strings out of string

Tags: php, string

I've been working on a code and finally got to the pint that it works but my PHP processes so much that I was wondering if there are any easier ways to fix my problem

The database I'm working with is filled with tracks from artists, and example from the table:

- composer_name = [@123:artist_display_name1] ft.
  [@58:artist_display_name2]
- track_title = Le Example ( [@798:artist_display_name3] Remix)

Where the number between the [ : is the artist_id (linked to artist profile) and the string between : ] is the display name for the artist (Sometimes artists use different names, that's why)

Now question is how to get the display names as fast as possible without brackets, but use the artist_id to perform another action (such as making a link out of it and put the artist_id in a database or something)

Comment: can you add more columns to your table to store `artist_id` and `display_name`?

Comment: I can, but with a lot of other tables involved it's basically making things to difficult

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more precise? Are you looking for DB optimization tips? Ways to parse the composer name and track title? It's difficult to know what you're looking for.

Comment: A php script to parse all the display names out of the string

Comment: So you want `[@123:artist_display_name1] ft. [@58:artist_display_name2]` become `'artist_display_name1 ft. artist_display_name2'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obligatory way would be to use a regex with `preg_match`:

```
function renderRow($rawRow) {
    return preg_replace("/\[@([0-9]*):([^\]]*)\]/", "$2", $rawRow);
}
```

Another way which is about 10x to 20x times faster (according to my quick benchmarks) is a more direct approach (O(N)):

```
function renderRow($rawRow) {
    $len = strlen($rawRow);
    $status = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $char = $rawRow[$i];
        if ($char === '[')
            $status = 1;
        else if ($status === 1) {
            if ($char === ':')
                $status = 2;
            continue;
        }
        else if ($status === 2 && $char === ']')
            $status = 0;
        else 
            $row .= $char;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @KeVin, worked like a charm, exactly what I needed and way faster! Used the second function by the way! Thanks again!